# Reset "at" command counter

Tags: linux

Somebody help me how to reset the "at" command counter. Let's say I have 1000 "at" jobs then I need to reset the "at" command counter so that it goes back to zero and it will not increment to very high number?

Comment: The sequence number is in  /var/spool/at/.SEQ  (mighjt be dependant on your 'at' implementation. You should not reset or meddle with it.

Comment: I use these to schedule a task in my program and my program will run in loops and the jobs would increment in a very large number after some time, and I'm thinking that if that time would come it might cause trouble in my program...=)

Comment: I too am interested in the answer to this question. I checked out my `/var/spool/at/.SEQ` file and it merely contains "0000c" (without the quotes). What is the meaning of this? Would it be safe to assume that the at daemon would reset the job numbers itself if they were to reach INT_MAX (or the max for whatever type stores the job number). For a 32bit unsigned integer, this number would be 4,294,967,295.. That's a whole lot of `at` jobs, but you never know! I'll keep researching and hope

Answer (score 6):

The at counter is in Hex and counts 5 digit so that brings to a max count of 1048574 (ffffe). When the max count is reached, the counter reset automatically to 0.

You could reset the counter manually by changing the `/var/spool/at/.SEQ` file to 00000. But if you really want to reset manually the counter, I would suggest you to remove all pending at jobs in the queue before you do so.

Comment: Removing all pending jobs in the queue does *not* seem to reset the jobs id counter.

Comment: @Victor I think the point of emptying the queue is not to trigger a counter reset, but to avoid id clashes. For instance, if you have a job registered as 2 then reset the id counter manually to 0, you might get into trouble a couple of jobs later because the id 2 will already exist.

Comment: @iago-lito You're right, I misunderstood the last bit there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current counter with:

```bash
echo "ibase=16; $(cat /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" | bc
```

To reset it, just change the hex value to zero and restart the `at` daemon:

```bash
printf '%04x' 0 > /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ
systemctl restart atd
```